# How to check whether a number is prime? (Mathematically)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Once while solving a numerical this question came to my mind. All of us know that numbers which have only two factors $1$ and itself is called prime. But I want to know if there is some standard method to check whether a number is prime or not? I know the following two methods but they are very inefficient.

-**Method 1**-:I know that prime numbers greater than 3 are of the form 6n+1 or 6n-1. But the converse is not true. One may say that it will remove most of the options but as we go higher the number of primes reduce and this method becomes less effective. 
-**Method 2**-:Another way could be to divide it with all the prime numbers less than it square root. But for large numbers it becomes very tedious.

> -**Question**-: Is there a mathematical way other than the above two to check whether a number is prime or not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: What do you mean with "mathematical way" ?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the non-mathematical way.  Maybe ask the Oracle at Delphi.

Comment: A sort of formula or something similar

Comment: Wilson's theorem states that an integer $n>1$ is prime if and only if $$\ n\mid (n-1)!+1\ $$ but this is of no practical use. The best known method is the Adleman-Pomerance-Rumely test (APR) or alternative the Elliptic curve primality proving method (ECPP). Miller Rabin's test gives a high probability that the number is prime when the test is passed and probability $1$ that the number is composite if it fails. But all these tests are too complex for hand calculation.

Comment: A "formula" for a quick decision is unknown and very unlikely to exist.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of primarily tests and the problem you are referring to is a popular problem. The fact is much beyond $10^{10^{4}}$ even most computer checks we have take an immense amount of time. As I said though there are many primarily tests that you can look through, just Google "primality tests".